# Magento 2: Product MassDelete issue

Tags: magento2.2

There is an issue encounter while using mass delete functionality at the catalog product. I am using Magento 2.2.2 setup.
Steps to replicate this issue:
- Select multiple products and submit delete action.
- Refresh the product list page open at another browser or another PC with the same or different admin account.
It will delete all the products of your store.
I fell prey two times.

Please help me to avoid this.

Comment: See the https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/15935 and related issues. 2.2.2 is old version, many issues were fixed since.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug on Magento. Please see here
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/19533

You need to rewrite the following classes via preference

```
Magento/Catalog/Controller/Adminhtml/Product/MassDelete.php
Magento/Ui/Component/MassAction/Filter.php
```

And apply the code changes found in this commit
https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/7028b311c05

Answer (score 0):

I got solution. I know that this is not reliable but it works for me. I made changes in Massdelete controller.

```
$count = count($collection); // newly added
foreach ($collection as $product) {
$this->productRepository->delete($product);
$productDeleted++;
if($count == $productDeleted){break;} // newly added
}
```

And now i am going to override this controller. And Looking forward to correct answer.